# python requests - post files multipart (http-status-code-400)

Tags: python, file-upload, python-requests, multipartform-data, fastapi

Using requests 2.26.0. I want to post a files to a server.

The result code below with fastapi swagger ui is fine,
but i get  from python code :
{"detail":"There was an error parsing the body"}

```
@router.post("/send/{email}")
async def send(email: str , files: List[UploadFile] = File(...)):
    return user.send(email, files)
```

and the send function :

```
def send(email: str, files):
    for file in files:
        with open(f'{file.filename}', "wb") as buffer:
            shutil.copyfileobj(file.file, buffer)
    print(email)
    send_email(email, 'F:/PROJECT/scan2excel/input/ss.xls')
    return {'file_name':'good'}
```

I test from main:

```
def upload_data(self, files_paths):
    url = 'http://localhost:8000/user/send/'+str(self.email)
    headers = {'Content-Type':'multipart/form-data; charset=utf-8; boundary=---- WebKitFormBoundary9JTSxAotKGVAuzQF'}
    f={"file": ("filename", open('F:/PROJECT/scan2excel/input/1.jpg', "rb"), "image/jpeg")}
    response = requests.post(url, files=f, headers=headers)
```

Comment: Why are you setting the boundary header yourself? I'm also guessing that a JPEG file don't have UTF-8 as its charset?

Comment: I have same error with :   headers = {'Content-Type':'multipart/form-data'}

Comment: You shouldn't have to manipulate the headers yourself at all; just let requests do it for you.

Answer (score 0):

The result on fastapi swagger ui:

https://ibb.co/XyGtXMK

response :

https://ibb.co/k0fYKQG